# Make Base URL at Frontend using Javascript (development, APIs and production)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, url

How to make base url that works with http, https, localhost, port and actual domain regardless of the development and deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to make a base url that will work under all scenarios or conditions regardless of the http/https protocols, port, localhost and actual domain whether it's in development or it's deployment/production.

So, I came up with this basic thing to handle local serve and build for production by using simple javascript.

**Basics**

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host;
```

This base url will be computed on the runtime and decide the actual protocol and actual host name.

**Advance**

If you want to change the port for API calls for different ports with different microservices, you can also use this function

```
function changePortForAPI(baseUrl, port) {
    var host = baseUrl.split("//");
    var res = host[1].split(":");
    res[1] = port;
    var result = host[0]+"//"+res[0] +":"+ res[1];
    return result;
}
```

Note: this 'changePortForAPI(baseUrl, port)' is for the development purposes because on build there is no use of port for API calls because it will be handled by server like Apache and Nginx etc.

SO, to detect localhost/development part and use different ports for API calls , you can use

```
function inDevelopment(baseUrl){
    var index = baseUrl.indexOf("localhost");
    if(index > 0){
      return true;  
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

After the detection of development mode you can use "changePortForAPI" function for API calls that will run fine on development and deployment as well.

**Edited:**

```
function inDevelopment(baseUrl){
    var host = baseUrl.split("//");
    var index = host[1].indexOf(":");
    if(index > 0){
      return true;  
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

This edited function is fine when you consider to commit the changes and you are using network ip that is separate from other developer.

Comment: The self-answer is fine but not always practical in real scenarios to stick to window.location. It could be not localhost but something else, like custom domain specified in hosts, or local network IP. It makes more sense to specify base urls explicitly in environment variables, this is supported by framework-specific tools because it's a must. *development purposes because on build there is no use of port for API calls because it will be handled by server like Apache and Nginx etc* - mapping API endpoints to a server on another port can be handled by proxy server, provided by Vue CLI, etc.

Comment: But I think window.location is fine for the real scenarios in terms of getting protocol and host as it also catches the specified hosts or local IP on the network. For the development purposes user can change this line 
`var index = baseUrl.indexOf("localhost");` to `var index = baseUrl.indexOf("127.0.0.1");` or `var index = baseUrl.indexOf("192.168.34.3");`  to detect the inDevelopment mode. 
Because it's only JavaScript nothing to do with frontend frameworks. Because each has separate method but this simple approach can work without considering the framework and domain server.

Comment: JS has nothing to do with frameworks, but apps do, they are tied to a specific setup. *For the development purposes user can change this line* - and then you end up with locally modified file that shouldn't be ever committed by accident. I ran into this problem many times so I know it from my own experience.

Comment: Yeah I know JS has nothing to do with frameworks that's why I have mentioned "regardless of the framework". But thanks for nice catch that we can't commit this thing. due to local IP etc. But I have a hack for this and it's tested.

function inDevelopment(baseUrl){
 var host = baseUrl.split("//");
    var index = host[1].indexOf(":");
    if(index > 0){
      return true;  
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}

I'm going to add this in the awnser