# VueJS + Django Rest Framework in dockers

Tags: django, docker, vue.js, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have a VueJS front end and a Django Rest Framework Backend which are independant (Django does not serve my VueJS app)

In local they work very well together but after using a docker-compose to deploy them on the server they don't want to communicate anymore. I can see my frontend but the axios requests get a TimeOut.

How it's made in my docker compose:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  intern:
    external: false
  extern:
    external: true

services:
  backend:
    image: #from_registry
    container_name: Backend
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - intern
    volumes:
      - statics:/app/static_assets/
      - medias:/app/media/
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    container_name: Db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ****
    networks:
      - intern
    volumes:
      - pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  frontend:
    image: from_registry
    container_name: Frontend
    volumes:
      - statics:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - medias:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    env_file:
      - ../.env.local
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - intern
      - extern
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.site.rule=Host(`dev.x-fantasy.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.site.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.site.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.port=80

volumes:
  pgdb:
  statics:
  medias:
```

In my AxiosConfiguration I put:

```
baseURL="http://backend:8000"
```

And my front try to access on this URL but get a timeout error.

In the console I have an error

```
xhr.js:177 POST https://backend:8000/api/v1/token/login net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

It seems that there is a https in place of the http. Can it come from here?

Any idea how to make them communicate?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this? because on deployment you don't need to specify port
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668223/make-base-url-at-frontend-using-javascript-development-apis-and-production]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck with that, I think the problem is more related to comunication between dockers