# Remove localhost:8080 from axios request url

Tags: vue.js

I am having a problem when I make a request to backend. `Axios` still writing `localhost` as a base url and adding the backend url after that.

> GET http://localhost:8080/127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects 404 (Not Found)

I did tried a couple of thing. First I tried to change `vue-router`'s base url. In `env.development` I wrote a `VUE_APP_ROUTER_BASE_URL="/"` and add it to router config.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.VUE_APP_ROUTER_BASE_URL,
    routes
  })
  
export default router
```

But this didn't worked out. Then I tried to change axios baseUrl directly like `axios.defaults.baseUrl = "/"` But this didn't worked out too... I am not sure, what I am missing, any other idea how to rearrange baseUrl when I make request to backend.

Comment: dont give complete in url in your  post
if you are doing this axios.get('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects')
replace it by only part after the base like
axios.get('/api/projects')

Comment: Did you have `http://` prefix in `VUE_APP_ROUTER_BASE_URL`?

Answer (score 2):

you should add "/" at first of the backend url,
the "/" delete everything befor your new url
or maybe the problem of a vue-cli app, try setting publicPath or baseUrl in your production and/or development environment.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem so I came up with basic solution to make URL that will meet every requirement whether it's development and deployment and APIs calls and push to source control etc.

[Make Base URL at Frontend using Javascript (development, APIs and production)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668223/make-base-url-at-frontend-using-javascript-development-apis-and-production)

Otherwise you will go back and forward by putting localhost in development and removing loalhost in deployment and changing ports for APIs

Note: It's independent of framework, you can use it wherever you like with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Nuxt application, I was able to solve this by changing my `.env` file name, from `baseURL` to something else i.e `GATEWAY_ENDPOINT`, and that solved it for me.